# Perl - Reading Specific Lines from a CSV file

Tags: perl, csv, text-parsing

I'm looking to read a certain "category" from a .csv file that looks something like this:

```
Category 1, header1, header2, header3,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
Category 2, header1, header2, header3,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
Category 3, header1, header2, header3,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
          , data, data, data,...
```

Let's say I wanted to print only the data from a specific "category"... how would I go about doing this?

ie: I want to print Category 2 data, the output should look like:

```
Category 2, header1, header2, header3,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
          , data, data, data,...
```

Comment: Have a look at [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS)

Comment: I forgot to mention; I can't download modules/source code at work...

Comment: You could take a try at implementing a simple one on your own, but here are some reasons why that would be a bad idea: http://tburette.github.io/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/

Comment: @user3707618: Then download it at home and take it in on a flash drive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your data includes quoted fields, like `a,b,c,"complicated field, quoted",e,f,g` there is no advantage in using `Text::CSV` over a simple `split /,/`.

This example categorizes the data into a hash that you can access simply and directly. I have used `Data::Dump` only to show the contents of the resulting data structure.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'mydata.csv';

my $category;
my %data;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my @data = split /,/;
  my $cat = shift @data;
  $category = $cat if $cat =~ /\S/;
  push @{ $data{$category} }, \@data;
}

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper \%data;
```

**output**

```
{
  "Category 1" => [
                    [" header1", " header2", " header3", "..."],
                    [" data", " data", " data", "..."],
                    [" data", " data", " data", "..."],
                    [" data", " data", " data", "..."],
                  ],
  "Category 2" => [
                    [" header1", " header2", " header3", "..."],
                    [" data", " data", " data", "..."],
                    [" data", " data", " data", "..."],
                    [" data", " data", " data", "..."],
                  ],
  "Category 3" => [
                    [" header1", " header2", " header3", "..."],
                    [" data", " data", " data", "..."],
                    [" data", " data", " data", "..."],
                    [" data", " data", " data", "..."],
                  ],
}
```

---

**Update**

If all you want is to separate a given section of the file then there is no need to put it into a hash. This program will do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($file, $wanted) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, '<', $file;

my $category;

while (<$fh>) {
  my ($cat) = /\A([^,]*)/;
  $category = $cat if $cat =~ /\S/;
  print if $category eq $wanted;
}
```

Run it like this on the command line

```
get_category.pl mydata.csv 'Category 2' > cat2.csv
```

**output**

```
Category 2, header1, header2, header3,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
          , data, data, data,...,
          , data, data, data,...
```

Comment: Is there a way of printing the data without the use of Data::Dump?

Comment: I have changed my code to use `Data::Dumper` instead. It is a core module that is part of a standard installation of Perl, and so shouldn't need installing. It doesn't produce such neat results as `Data::Dump` though.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to Perl... How would I print a specific category to an output file?

Comment: Okay I've added another solution that selects just a single category that you specify on the command line

Answer (score 0):

If that output is definitely what you want, then you could do this with a perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne "$p = 0 if /^Category/;$p = 1 if /^Category 2/;print if $p;" myfile.csv
```

Comment: Why? It turns off printing when it hits "Category" at SOL, but turns it back on if it hits "Category 2".

(sorry - had trouble adding code in an edit)

Comment: Oh I see, my bad.. Wouldn't this keep printing into "Category 3" though?

Comment: No, it will continue printing until it hits the string 'Category' that is not 'Category 2', so it stops printing when it hits 'Category 3'.

Comment: Ahh... it seems I'm pretty slow today