# Number of subarrays array of arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm trying to get the number of "subarrays" in an array of arrays...

i.e.:

Original:

```
@array = (("a","b","c"),(1,2,3),("q","w","e"));
```

Modified:

```
@array = (["a","b","c"],[1,2,3],["q","w","e"]);
```

How would I go about getting this number? (In this case, it would be 3.)

Comment: What does `print scalar(@array)` give you? I think the answer is 9 because the 'sub-arrays' don't exist -- they've been flattened into one array.  You'd need to use array references to get sub-arrays, with square brackets around the sub-arrays.

Comment: it outputs scalar(ARRAY(0x80872ec))

Comment: If it says `ARRAY(0xfoo)` you do not have what you are saying you have in your question. Please show real code, or if it's from a hash(ref) as said in a comment on an answer, please show real debug output.

Comment: Check your typing; that (`scalar(ARRAY(0x80872ec))` is nothing like what Perl 5.18.1 gives -- it gives 9.

Comment: I'm using the 2004 version of Perl... I can't use anything newer at work...

Comment: It is hard for people to help you accurately when you don't ask the question accurately.  Your change was highly non-trivial, but people had answered in good faith based on the original code.  It would be best to show an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), and the exact output you get from the code you post as the SSCCE.  If `print scalar(@array)` is not yielding 3 in the amended code, you might need to show us what `use Data::Dumper;` and `print Dumper(\@array);` prints.

Comment: Your version of Perl is actually not really relevant to this issue. The fact that you got different output was because of the `[ ]` vs `( )` in the way you retyped your code here.

Comment: Running `perl -v` should give you a version such as 5.6.2.  And it is years beyond time since your company upgraded.  That said, I don't think this is touching on behaviour that has changed since 2004, so what you show should work much the same on newer versions of Perl as well as your archaic one.

Comment: The way I typed my code there - with the round brackets instead - is not how I have it in my actual code... and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: What error? You have not talked about an error before. Please give us complete information or we cannot help you solve the problem. There are now three solutions as to how to count your array ref elements below. Have you tried any of them yet?

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned it on a different comment:

Comment: I get the following output using all of the methods mentioned here: ARRAY(0x80872ec)

Comment: That is not an error. It's telling us that there is an array reference inside the variable you are looking at. The `0x80872ec` is the memory address that Perl uses internally to store that array ref. If you see this kind of output, it tells you that you need to add more dereferencing. Dereferencing an array ref is done by adding `@{ array-ref-expression }` around your expression.

Comment: See my revised answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count **only** array refs inside an array ref, you can use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) together with the [`ref` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html). Assuming there can be other things as well as array refs inside your outer array ref, you can do it like this:

```
my @array = (["a","b","c"],[1,2,3],["q","w","e"], 4);
my $count = scalar grep { ref $_ eq 'ARRAY' } @array;
print $count;

__END__
3
```

It will look at each element of `@array` in turn, grab the ones that have a `ref` type of `ARRAY` and force the resulting list to scalar context, giving the number of elements.

---

Since you seem to have an hash ref that holds array refs with array refs, maybe changing it to this will do the trick. I assumed you could do the transfer yourself.

```
my $count = scalar grep { ref $_ eq 'ARRAY' } @{ $hashref->{element} };
```

Comment: If there only are array refs and you want to count all of elements, the other answers are already fine.

Answer (score 4):

you dont have any "subarrays".

```
my @array = (['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']);
```

and then just

```
print scalar @array;
```

which prints

```
3
```

you want an array of array, which can be done by having an array of `arrayref`s. An Array Reference can be created by using `[`,`]` square brackets.

```
my $array_ref = ['a','b','c'];
```

You can de-reference an `Arrayref` with an leading `@`:

```
print scalar @$array_ref;
# or an more readable version
print scalar @{ $array_ref }
```

Comment: I do have "subarrays", the way I had it originally in the question isn't how it is in my code.. sorry.

Comment: when I try printing it like that I get this output: scalar(ARRAY(0x80872ec))

Comment: @user3707618, You changed `scalar(@a)` to `"scalar($a)"`

Comment: @ikegami please look at the edits on the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Responding to modified question with info from below comment:

It sounds like what you ACTUALLY have is a hash of arrays as demonstrated in Borodin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24041312/1733163) to your previous question:

```
my %hash = (
    key => [ ["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3], ["q", "w", "e"] ],
);
```

In which case, to get the count, you need use `scalar` and dereference the array ref:

```
print scalar(@{$hash{key}}), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
3
```

Comment: There's not really a "multidimensional array".  What you have here is a an array of arrayrefs.

Comment: the way it's defined is arbitrary, I already have the array (it's reading from a hash)

Comment: @user3707618 Since you're reading from a hash, you need to dereference the value to actually get the count.

Comment: *"Same Error"* communicates nothing when you've not talked about an error before.